# Program not giving desired output as asked in the problem

Tags: c, file

I'm working on this problem:

Write a program to read a file and display contents with its line numbers.

Here's the code I have written:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void lineprint(int *line){
    *line=*line+1;
    printf ("Line %d",line);
}
int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("sample.txt","r");
    if (fp==NULL){
        printf ("File not Found");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        int line=1;
        printf ("Line %d\n",line);
        while ((fgetc (fp))!=EOF){
            printf ("%c",fgetc(fp));
            if ((fgetc(fp))=='\n'){
                lineprint(&line);
            }
        }   
    }
    fclose (fp);
return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting garbage output. Please please help.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), the documentation of your compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), to be used as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Can you please explain in little simpler terms?

Comment: Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) or of [sash](http://members.canb.auug.org.au/~dbell/)

Comment: @GirG Can you provide a portion of the `sample.txt` file?

Comment: Every time you call `fgetc`, a character is taken from the input stream, if available. Your code takes one character and checks for `EOF`. Then it takes a different character and prints it. Now the first one is lost. Then it takes a different character and compares it to `'\n'`. If it is not `'\n'`, then its value is lost. Rewrite your code so that it calls `fgetc` once and stores the result in an `int`. Then use the value of that `int` to decide whether you got an EOF, a character to print, or a new-line character.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That is not helpful. I too wish Stack Overflow were not subjected to some many complete novice questions, but comments like that are not helpful and comes across as snide.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can you please write the correct code and explain?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I couldn't get you completely.

Comment: @alex01011 My sample.txt file has

Comment: @alex01011 Hello World!

Comment: (in next line) Welcome to C programming!

Comment: Start with `do { int c = fgetc(fp); … } while (1);` and fill in the `…` part. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service; it is not appropriate to ask somebody to write code for you. You can ask questions to help you understand, but you need to figure out code for yourself or learn it somewhere else, such as from a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basicly when you call fgetc(), the inner pointer of the struct FILE return the first char size data from the file and moves the pointer by sizeOf(char).
also you did not increase the value of line.
I made a few aujustments to the code and it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    int letter;
    fp=fopen("test.txt","r");
    if (fp==NULL){
        printf ("File not Found");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        int line=1;
        printf ("Line %d\n",line);
        while ((letter = fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
            printf ("%c",letter);
            if (letter =='\n'){
                line++;
                printf ("Line %d\n",line);

            }
        }
    }
    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps, if you have any questions I will be happy to try and answer =)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You should you just save the character read into a variable and use that later. Also you should check again about pointers (derefernce is what you are looking for).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void lineprint(int *line){
    (*line)++; /* Dereference first */
    printf ("Line %d\n",*line); /* Dereference here */
}

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("sample.txt","r");

    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf ("File not Found");
        exit(0);
    }
    else 
    {
        int line = 1;
        int c = 0;

        printf ("Line %d\n",line);
        while ((c = fgetc (fp))!=EOF) /* Save the character read into a variable, use that later */
        { 
            printf ("%c",c);
            if (c =='\n'){
                lineprint(&line);
            }
        }   
    }
    fclose (fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just one query, why did you use int c instead of char c

Comment: @GirG Simple answer, in case you want to use other characters sets than ASCII in your file.

Comment: @alex01011: `int` is not needed to handle non-ASCII characters. `char` can generally do that, although `unsigned char` is better. `int` is needed because the return value from `fgetc` may be `EOF`, which is not a character value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree with your comment, I did not mention EOF since I just wanted to give a simple answer:)